# ProxyPassMatch directive problems

Tags: apache2, http-status-code-403

We have an environment with Apache 2.2.11 acting as front end to incoming connections to a Tomcat backend server. We are using the following directives in the http-ssl.conf, which works great when not trying to catch 403 errors:

SetEnvIf COMPANY EDLP 4.0.1 NLEDLPKEY=true

General setup for the virtual host 
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"

ServerName localhost:443 
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPassMatch / htp://tomcat.company.com**<-- been having issues with this directive (using only one "t" in http to bypass this sites new user can only post one URL per question limitation**

ProxyPassReverse / htp://tomcat.company.com

As you can see we are using the mod_access (now called mod_authz_host in Apache 2.2) module to pass a variable called NLEDLPKEY so that only (Internet Explorer) clients with this variable could access Tomcat via SSL. Also, I am trying to not only reverse proxy SSL connections, but also to redirect the 403 errors (for people without the variable) to a specified page (error_page.html). I have tried:

ProxyPassMatch "^[^(/error_page.html)]" htp://tomcat.company.com **and also tried**

ProxyPassMatch “^(?!/error_page.html)” htp://tomcat.company.com

to see if it is possible to redirect to the error page and not get the below message:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /RDS on this server. **<--RDS is just a directory-->**

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. 
Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9 Server at apache-company Port 443

Any help would be appreciated

R.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently - it took a bit of hunting but here's how I fixed it:

In `/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf` (Ubuntu - YMMV) change it to look like the following:

```
<Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

It's also important to note that for reverse proxies, it is not necessary to have `ProxyRequests On` configured and doing so in conjunction with `Allow from all` is hazardous. (Can be used by spammers to send mail via your proxy.)